# Windows batch -- save list of file names, excluding the list file itself

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Using Windows cmd.exe

```
dir /b /od > list.txt
```

creates a file whose last line is list.txt. How can I avoid having the string list.txt appear in the file list.txt?

Comment: `dir /b /od |findstr /v /b /e "list.txt" >list.txt` ?

Comment: That works, thanks. If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Comment: `Dir /B /OD>"%TEMP%\list.txt" && Move "%TEMP%\list.txt">Nul`

Comment: This works no matter the file name, that is, giving it just once: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /OD') do echo %%a>> list.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dir /b /od |findstr /v /b /e "list.txt" >list.txt
```

Probably there's a better way , but this is simple enough.

Comment: `/VX` would be simpler than `/V /B /E`!

Comment: @Compo - yes it will be. Probably it will be better even in terms of robustness because it will handle files with spaces in its names.